# What does sed $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' do?

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep

The command `sed $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g'` is printing each line of my .txt as-is.

What is it used for? I could not find it on google.

Eg:

```
    sed $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' *.txt | wc -l
    15909

    cat *.txt | wc -l
    15909
```

There are no edits done in the files whatsoever. What does this command do

Comment: `sed` is pretty heavy-handed for such a simple task. `tr -d` is likely faster and many implementations understand the same named character sets as used in this `sed` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sed` command removes any character that is not printable, and not tabs, from the content of each line of input.  The number of lines would not change (the newline characters are not removed as they are not part of the *content* of  the line), but the number of characters or bytes might.  Test again with `wc -c` for the number of bytes, `wc -m` for the number of characters.

The regular expression `[^...]` matches any single character (*actually collating element*) *not* within the `[...]`.  In this case, it's the character class `[:print:]` and the tab character.  The `$` at the start of the string makes `bash` replace `\t` with a literal tab character before calling `sed`.

The character class `[:print:]` matches characters that are printable in the current locale, i.e. alphanumeric characters, punctuation characters and space (but not tab which is a control character).

In other words, it deletes everything that is not a alphanumeric character, punctuation character, space or tab.

To write the result back to the file (an "in-place edit"), some `sed` implementations have a `-i` option for that; use `sed -i` or `sed -i ''` depending on the implementation.  Be sure that the correct output is produced first though, or you may destroy your data.

Comment: Oh the wc -c gives me different numbers, which means it does delete some characters. How to print the characters that it is deleting.? or Line numbers for ref?

Comment: Even though it removes certain chars, how come the timestamps do not change?

Comment: the dollar at the start means that the \t is a literal tab by the time sed sees it

Comment: @Jasen Cheers, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Viv The timestamp is not changed because no change is made to the file. The only thing that happens is that the lines are transformed an printed to the terminal.

Comment: @Viv Delete the `^` in `[^...]` to see what characters matches the inverse condition.

Comment: Oh thats brilliant, it does print, but its probably newline char i guess, its a blank screen but which file contains this in the directory how to find out?

Comment: @Viv `grep -H $'[^[:print:]\t]' *.txt`, possibly.